# How to get the message from a php file and send to another php file using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){

                    alert(msg);

                }
        });
```

I have written a ajax file to send some parameters to another file insert.php to send these parameters as mail. If the mail send has been successfully, it should send a message back to the main file to display it there. I have written the code for insert.php shown below :

```
<?php
 $date=$_POST['date'];
 $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date ));

 $time=$_POST['time'];
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $number=$_POST['number'];
 $mail=$_POST['mail'];
 $pname=$_POST['pname'];
 $ptype=$_POST['ptype'];
 $gender=$_POST['gender'];
 $comments=$_POST['comments'];
 $to  = 'df@gmail.com'; 
 $subject = 'Enquiry !!!!';


$message = ' A Customer has made a enquiry about a package  " '.$pname.'  "  whose Name is  "  '.$name.'  "  with Email-id   '.$mail.' and who    is  a  '.$gender.' and Contact Number is   '.$number.' and has send a message " '.$comments.' " on Date  '.$newDate .'  and Time  '.$time;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

$retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


if($retval == true)
{
  $msg = "YOUR ENQUIRY HAS BEEN SEND!!!!";
  echo $msg;

}else {
$msg = "YOUR ENQUIRY HAS NOT BEEN SEND!!!! PLEASE TRY AGAIN !!!";
echo $msg;
}
 ?>
```

I want to send the $msg value back to the php file from where the control came to display it there. How to get that message inside success function ? I tried to alert it, but it is not working.

Comment: Try `alert(result)`.

Comment: No..its not working !!!

Comment: i want to alert that particular message there...

Comment: Then define "not working". What _is_ happening? Are you getting errors in your web console? Can you see the AJAX request in your network tab of your developer tools etc. Do some debugging.

Comment: @lena What ever you echo from insert.php the result is your message . please try this you will get the result.please have look at below is the answer.

Comment: What's your console output? Don't output it with `alert`, try `console.log()`.

Comment: Do one thing just use this line: echo $retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); and remove all code and then check what will alert in your ajax response .... I think it must return 1 if mail send successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);// the resiult is your message.
    }
});
```

What ever you echo from insert.php the result is your message . please try this you will get the result. result is parameter for the function. The output of the ajax page will catch here only and process this result only.